# Section List not displaying

Tags: react-native

Following the React-Native tutorial and I'm unable to get the data to show.

When I do a console.log my data appears like so:

```
Array [
  Object {
    "data": Object {
      "address": "8753 2nd Street",
      "id": "5507",
      "inspection_date": "2019-03-27",
      "inspection_time": "07:00:00",
      "inspection_time_display": "07.00 AM",
      "inspector": "Frank",
    },
    "key": "5507",
    "title": "8753 2nd Street",
  },
  Object {
    "data": Object {
      "address": "11445 Paramount ave ",
      "id": "5505",
      "inspection_date": "2019-03-23",
      "inspection_time": "10:30:00",
      "inspection_time_display": "10.30 AM",
      "inspector": "Fabian Hernandez",
    },
    "key": "5505",
    "title": "11445 Paramount ave ",
  },
]
```

I have the "data" and "title" sections as indicated in most tutorials.

My component is like this:

```
 <Container>
    <Header />
    <Content>
    <SectionList
      renderItem={({item, index, section}) => <Text key={index}>{item}</Text>}
      renderSectionHeader={({section: {title}}) => (
        <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{title}</Text>
      )}
      sections={this.state.dataSource}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
    />
    </Content>
  </Container>
```

This is what I think is happening but I'm obviously wrong since something isn't adding up.
Looping through "sections"

```
renderItem={({item, index, section}) => <Text key={index}>{item}</Text>}
```

I'm expecting this above to get the "data".

Getting title:

```
renderSectionHeader={({section: {title}}) => (
            <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{title}</Text>
          )}
```

I'm expecting this above to get the "title".  What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the data key in each of your section objects need to be an array unto itself. Example:

```
const mySectionedData = [
  {
    title: 'section 1',
    data: [ 
      {address: '123 street', name: 'me'}, 
      {address: '456 street', name: 'you}
    ]
  },
  {
    title: 'section 2',
    data: [ 
      {address: '789 street', name: 'us'} 
    ]
  }
]
```

This then lets you access `{title, data}` from each of your sections which allows the section list to then render your section header from title, and a list of items from the data array.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Using the above example I get "Invariant Violation.  Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {address, name}).  @krewllobster

Comment: You cant display directly whole json. You will need to use                                                             renderItem={({item, index, section}) =><View> <Text key={index}>{item.address}</Text><Text key={index}>{item.id}</Text></View>}  and so on.

Comment: Combination of this answer and yours solved it for me @shrutigarg

Comment: I was also unable to see my section headers, and this fixed my issue. Thanks